# Deep copy of backbone model with its prototype chain

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to deep copy backbone model. `clone` method doesn't make deep copy, the reference to the `attributes` object gets copied to the clone. I've accomplished this with the following:

```
var model = Backbone.Model();
// modifying model
var clone = _.merge(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(model)), model);
```

Are there any better options?

Comment: `new Backbone.Model(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(model.toJSON())))`

Comment: thanks, how's it better than my approach?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any better options?

Use [benchmark.js](https://benchmarkjs.com/) to compare the performance of this versus native methods:

```js
var bench1 = new Benchmark(
  {'fn':merge_object, 'cycles':0,'count':1,'name':'merge','async':true}
);
var bench2 = new Benchmark(
  {'fn':parse_object, 'cycles':0,'count':1,'name':'parse','async':true}
);

var foo = {"bar": {"baz": {"bop": "zero"} } };

function merge_object()
  {
  var clone = _.merge(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(foo)), foo);
  }

function parse_object()
  {
  new Backbone.Model(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo)))
  }

function log(result){console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)))};

bench1.on('complete', log);
bench2.on('complete', log);
bench1.run();
bench2.run();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.6/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/benchmark/2.1.2/benchmark.min.js"></script>
```

**References**

- [Structure Clone CommonJS Module](https://github.com/tcr/structured-clone)
- [JS Object Clone](https://github.com/dankogai/js-object-clone)
- [MDN: Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)